# libuv timer:i can not get the output from console

Tags: c, libuv

I am newer to libuv. Today i meet a question that i can not get the outout from console. this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <uv.h>

void timer_cb(uv_timer_t *handle, int status);

int main() {
  uv_loop_t *loop;
  loop = uv_default_loop();
  uv_timer_t time_req;
  uv_timer_init(loop, &time_req);

  uv_timer_start(&time_req, (void *)timer_cb, 2000, 2000);


  return uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
}

void timer_cb(uv_timer_t *handle, int status) {
  printf("%s", "cb.....");
}
```

thanks :）

Comment: The `stdout` file handle (which `printf` writes to) is by default *line buffered*. That means output is buffered until there is a newline, when the buffer is flushed. That's why you should always *end* your output with a newline.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude
oh..i forgot that. printf("%s\n", "cb...") is work.
thanks a lot :）

Answer (score 0):

You just need to flush your output using `fflush` like...

```
printf("%s", "cb.....");
fflush(stdout);
```